# Why does Django return http 200 if form data is invalid?

Tags: django, http-status-codes

AFAIK Django uses this way to handle forms:

1. GET: client receives HTML with input elements
2. user fills out the form
3. user submits form: http POST
4. server/Django validates the form. In this case it is invalid
5. server sends HTML containg the same form and an error message to the user. With http status 200.

Wouldn't it make more sense to use a different http status code if the data is invalid?

PS: I know the [Post/Redirect/Get](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern. The question is: "Why 200 if the data is invalid?"

Comment: It does a redirect after a *succesful* POST request. If not, it often rerenders the page with a form that displays the errors, hence the 200. But one could indeed pass a different status code.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I removed "redirect after post" from the question to avoid confusion.

Comment: the code 200 is the default django http response code, and no problems to change it if you think it is need.

Comment: Would [because they didn't want to](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/22591) be a valid answer?

Comment: @Sayse "they don't want" is not the answer. But the explanation in the ticket might reveal their reasons. Thank you for this link!